# Configuring Server Intelligent Agent with CA signed p12 certificate?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, openssl-cms

I have a cert signed by a CA, and I need to "extract" the info from it for Server Intelligent Agent (SIA).

I converted p12 to jks for Tomcat already, but SIA needs DER files and private.key.

How do I get `cacert.der`, `servercert.der` and `private.key` from a CA signed p12 cert?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Thinking that since i have the p12 CA signed certificate i need to use openssl to extract the files that i need in pem format.. than i need to use sslc to convert them to der... and use sslc to create the dir /SSL ... one reason is that i do not have openssl at the server where i need the der files and also i could not find documentation sslc commands - how to get the needed info for the files from CA signed certificate. Any thoughts?